# Reproduzir vídeo de uma playlist de acordo com data e hora tem como?

Tags: javascript, html

olá eu estou criando um sistema de webtv/playlist tenho o seguinte código html :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<video id="player-video" controls controlsList="nodownload" class="player-video" ></video>
</body>
</html>
```

e um script assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //iniciando o script

(function () {
    var playerVideo = document.getElementById("player-video");
    var current = 0;
    var videos = [];

    videos.push("video_1.mp4");
    videos.push("video_2.mp4");
    videos.push("video_3.mp4");
    videos.push("video_4.mp4");
    videos.push("video_5.mp4");

    function nextVideo() {
        playerVideo.src = videos[current];

        current++;

        playerVideo.play();

        if (current >= videos.length) {
            current = 0;
        }
    }

    playerVideo.addEventListener("ended", nextVideo);

    nextVideo();

})();
</script>
```

até ai nada demais,mais o que eu quero mesmo e que dependendo da hora ele reproduza um vídeo específico exemplo:

> quando for 12h00 ele reproduza o video_1.mp4

> quando for 13h00 ele reproduza o video_2.mp4

fui claro?,e tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode sim. Você terá de ir buscar a hora local utilizado a classe Date.

```
var date = new Date();
if(date.getHours() == 12){
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    video.src = urls[i++];
    video.play();
}
```

Exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/c81ozf5s/1/

Answer (score 0):

Bom, na lógica de dados...

Você pode usar o objeto **Date**!

> Pra acessar os valores do objeto, deve primeiro inseri-lo em uma
> variável:
>
> ```
> var date = new Date();
> ```

A partir daí, você tem fácil acesso às informações da *string* usando métodos nativos, como o `.getHours`(Que é o que lhe interessa no momento) e inserir numa outra variável.

> **Aplicação:**
>
> [image: Objeto Date() dentro da variável]
>
> (Chamado às 20 horas)

E assim, você pode elaborar uma condicional ou um `switch()`a partir disso, e modificar o vídeo a ser exibido a partir de uma variável pré-definida que recebe tal elemento HTML.

Exemplo:

```js
let video = document.querySelector('#video0');


switch (hora){

case 13: video = document.querySelector('#video1') 
}
```

E basicamente é isso aí, você pode escolher um bom evento na página pra ativar uma função de checar a hora e, caso seja esta ou aquela, mudar a partir do seu gosto.

> Essa foi a forma mais simples que consegui de explicar, e os exemplos
> estão meio "*hard coded*", mas era apenas para demonstrar o princípio da coisa, espero ter ajudado.